# Database Tables remove all the records automatically

Tags: mysql

I am having issue with the database tables.
Even I have changed the server but still my issue is same.
Today in morning, Automatically the `admin` table became empty. Auto matically deleted All the records. and now an hour ago one more table gone empty. I have ran the query logging. But I could not find any delete command or Alter table command anywhere. I am not sure what is happening.

But it is very critical issue to delete records automatically. This is too risky.

EDITED:

Here are the Query Log file part related to this table.. I do not know why this is again and again appearing in log. Now the `competitions` table is deleting its records again & again

```
2048 Quit
                  2049 Connect  musicuploads@localhost as anonymous on
                  2049 Query    SELECT @@version, @@version_comment
                  2049 Query    SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
                  2049 Query    SET lc_messages = 'en_US'
                  2050 Connect  musicuploads@localhost as anonymous on
                  2050 Query    SHOW TABLES FROM `musicupl_musicuploads`
                  2049 Query    SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`
                  2049 Query    SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
                  2050 Query    SHOW TABLES FROM `musicupl_musicuploads`
                  2049 Query    SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`
                  2049 Query    SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS'
                  2049 Query    SELECT DATABASE()
                  2049 Init DB  musicupl_musicuploads
                  2049 Query    CHECKSUM TABLE `competitions`
                  2049 Query    SHOW WARNINGS
                  2049 Query    SELECT @@lower_case_table_names
                  2049 Query    SHOW  COLUMNS FROM `musicupl_musicuploads`.`competitions`
                  2049 Query    SHOW INDEXES FROM `musicupl_musicuploads`.`competitions`
                  2049 Query    SHOW CREATE TABLE `musicupl_musicuploads`.`competitions`
                  2049 Query    SHOW  COLUMNS FROM `musicupl_musicuploads`.`competitions`
                  2049 Query    SELECT TABLE_NAME
            FROM information_schema.VIEWS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'musicupl_musicuploads'
                AND TABLE_NAME = 'competitions'
                  2049 Query    SELECT `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`USER_PRIVILEGES` WHERE GRANTEE='''musicuploads''@''localhost''' AND PRIVILEGE_TYPE='TRIGGER'
                  2049 Query    SELECT `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` WHERE GRANTEE='''musicuploads''@''localhost''' AND PRIVILEGE_TYPE='TRIGGER' AND 'musicupl_musicuploads' LIKE `TABLE_SCHEMA`
                  2049 Query    SELECT TABLE_NAME
            FROM information_schema.VIEWS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'musicupl_musicuploads'
                AND TABLE_NAME = 'competitions'
                  2049 Query    SELECT TABLE_NAME
            FROM information_schema.VIEWS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'musicupl_musicuploads'
                AND TABLE_NAME = 'competitions'
                  2049 Query    SELECT *,
                `TABLE_SCHEMA`       AS `Db`,
                `TABLE_NAME`         AS `Name`,
                `TABLE_TYPE`         AS `TABLE_TYPE`,
                `ENGINE`             AS `Engine`,
                `ENGINE`             AS `Type`,
                `VERSION`            AS `Version`,
                `ROW_FORMAT`         AS `Row_format`,
                `TABLE_ROWS`         AS `Rows`,
                `AVG_ROW_LENGTH`     AS `Avg_row_length`,
                `DATA_LENGTH`        AS `Data_length`,
                `MAX_DATA_LENGTH`    AS `Max_data_length`,
                `INDEX_LENGTH`       AS `Index_length`,
                `DATA_FREE`          AS `Data_free`,
                `AUTO_INCREMENT`     AS `Auto_increment`,
                `CREATE_TIME`        AS `Create_time`,
                `UPDATE_TIME`        AS `Update_time`,
                `CHECK_TIME`         AS `Check_time`,
                `TABLE_COLLATION`    AS `Collation`,
                `CHECKSUM`           AS `Checksum`,
                `CREATE_OPTIONS`     AS `Create_options`,
                `TABLE_COMMENT`      AS `Comment`
            FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` t
            WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` COLLATE utf8_bin
                IN ('musicupl_musicuploads')
                AND t.`TABLE_NAME` COLLATE utf8_bin = 'competitions' ORDER BY Name ASC
                  2049 Query    SELECT `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`USER_PRIVILEGES` WHERE GRANTEE='''musicuploads''@''localhost''' AND PRIVILEGE_TYPE='TRIGGER'
                  2049 Query    SELECT `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` WHERE GRANTEE='''musicuploads''@''localhost''' AND PRIVILEGE_TYPE='TRIGGER' AND 'musicupl_musicuploads' LIKE `TABLE_SCHEMA`
                  2050 Quit
```

Comment: Does anyone else have write access to the database?

Comment: No it is totally new server. And otherthan me no access to any other

Comment: I found a related question on DBA Stack Exchange that might help. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90283/mysql-script-to-automate-creation-of-audit-history-tables-and-triggers

Comment: No that is not helpful for me.. My issue is different

Comment: @spencer7593 Dear the Database is fully in my control it is a totally new purchased VPS server. 
MariaDB is Installed on it. I have a bigger database having about 60+ tables in it. but there are some tables which are going empty after 24 hours or sometime after 1 week. very important and critical data losses. And there is no DELETE REMOVE ROW or Alter table queries working. I checked in query log.